# phpvirtualbox Error logging in to vboxwebsrv

Tags: php, xampp, virtualbox

I just installed phpVirtualBox and XAMPP and have turned on vboxwebsrv i can access the server but as soon as i login it says "Error logging in to vboxwebsrv" and then i get this error.

```
 Exception Object
(
    [message:protected] => Error logging in to vboxwebsrv.
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 64
    [file:protected] => C:\xampp\htdocs\phpvirtualbox\endpoints\api.php
    [line:protected] => 134
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

I assume i need to unprotect some files but i don't know what i need to edit to do that.

Comment: I believe it was something to do with Windows 10 firewall

Answer (score 0):

you must enter **the username and password** in the **config.php** file.
if you use **linux** you can enter **root as username** and password.
if you use **windows** you can enter the **email of the microsoft** account and **the password**